# Store a value manually setted in Database

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, persistence, facade

I have a jsf form in which the user type an int and a string value, which are stored in database after clicking on a Save button.

```
<h:form id="TbtestCreateForm">
    <p:inputText value="#{tbtestController.selected.name}" />
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{tbtestController.saveNew}" value="#{myBundle.Save}" />
</h:form>
```

I'm using EJBs with façade pattern, which does the CRUD actions defined in AbstractController class, which uses the AbstractFacade that 'binds' the entity class.

What I need is to **hard code/set manually** the string value in the form and store it in database along with the int value informed by the user, in the same operation (the same object).

I've tried to do as below, but no success:

```
@Named
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

@Inject
TbtestController tbtestController;

private String myName;
//GETTERS AND SETTERS

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    myName = "some foo name";
    Tbtest myTbtest = new Tbtest();
    myTbtest.setName(myName);
    tbtestController.setSelected(myTbtest);
    tbtestController.saveNew(null); // to simulate what the savNew method do
}
```

I've created a small netbeans project available to be cloned at: https://github.com/f6750699/webAppTest.git

Below, follows 2 methods defined in the AbstractController class:

The **saveNew** method:

```
public void saveNew(ActionEvent event) {
    String msg = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/MyBundle").getString(itemClass.getSimpleName() + "Created");
    persist(PersistAction.CREATE, msg);
    if (!isValidationFailed()) {
        items = null; // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.
    }
}
```

The **persist** method:

```
private void persist(PersistAction persistAction, String successMessage) {
    if (selected != null) {
        this.setEmbeddableKeys();
        try {
            if (persistAction != PersistAction.DELETE) {
                this.ejbFacade.edit(selected);
            } else {
                this.ejbFacade.remove(selected);
            }
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(successMessage);
        } catch (EJBException ex) {
            Throwable cause = JsfUtil.getRootCause(ex.getCause());
            if (cause != null) {
                if (cause instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
                    ConstraintViolationException excp = (ConstraintViolationException) cause;
                    for (ConstraintViolation s : excp.getConstraintViolations()) {
                        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(s.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    String msg = cause.getLocalizedMessage();
                    if (msg.length() > 0) {
                        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(msg);
                    } else {
                        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/MyBundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }
}
```

I really appreciate some help with it, because I got stuck on it for a while already.

Thanks in advance.

---

Paul Morris solution

I've concentrated in one class, as Paul suggested:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TbtestController extends AbstractController<Tbtest> {

@EJB
private TbtestFacade ejbFacade;

public TbtestController() {
    super(Tbtest.class); //-> there is already an invocation here, see below
}

@PostConstruct
@Override
public void init() {
    super.setFacade(ejbFacade);
//Paul Morris solution below
    myName = "some foo name";
    this.setMyName(myName);
    this.saveNew(null); // to simulate what the savNew method do
}

private String myName;

public void setMyName(String name) {
    myName = name;
}

@Override
public void saveNew(ActionEvent event) {
    this.getSelected().setName(myName);
    //super.(event); // -> invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the subclass constructor, but there is already one invocation, see above. Then, I've tried to invoke the super method:
   super.saveNew(event); // but this didn't resolved, as it launches a NullPointerException, see below.
 }
}
```

The Exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void beans.TbtestController.init() on beans.TbtestController@37668b21
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at beans.TbtestController.saveNew(TbtestController.java:40)
at beans.TbtestController.init(TbtestController.java:29)
... 87 more
```

Comment: "*but no success*". Is this EL `#{tbtestController.selected.name}` evaluated to `null`? Do you get some errors/exceptions or something even completely different/weird happens?

Comment: No, this EL is working fine as the user type the string value, but I want him to type only the integer, the string should be manually setted. What I've tried is `#{myBean.myName}`, and got a `value="#{myBean.myName}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'myBean' resolved to null`. I need to set/hard code the value in some class, but I don't know where...

Comment: The default scope of a CDI bean is `@Dependent`. Can you try designating an appropriate scope of your need or that bean is supposed to have that `@Dependent` scope?

Comment: The mentioned exception was already using @SessionScoped in the MyBean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this all wrong. Leave the AbstractController class as generated. Instead, modify the derived class, TbtestController and add a property for the hard coded string. Then override the saveNew method, like so:

```
private String myName;

public void setMyName(String name) {
    myName = name;
}

@Override
public void saveNew(ActionEvent event) {
    this.getSelected().setName(myName);
    super.saveNew(event);    

}
```

Your bean method should then be coded something like this:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    myName = "some foo name";
    tbtestController.setMyName(myName);

}
```

though I'm not certain why you have the MyBean class at all. Hard code the string in the Controller and then just use the Controller saveNew method in the form like you have at the top of your question.

**UPDATE**

Try this ...

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TbtestController extends AbstractController<Tbtest> {

    @EJB
    private TbtestFacade ejbFacade;

    public TbtestController() {
        super(Tbtest.class); //-> there is already an invocation here, see below
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.setFacade(ejbFacade);
        //Paul Morris solution below
        myName = "";

    }

    private String myName;

    public void setMyName(String name) {
        myName = name;
    }

    public String getMyName(String name) {
        if (myName.isEmpty()) {
            myName = "Default Value";
        }
        return myName;
    }


    @Override
    public void saveNew(ActionEvent event) {
        this.getSelected().setName(this.getMyName(myName));
        super.saveNew(event); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Paul Morris, I really appreciate your help, but I've tried to use your solution and there are some few problems yet. Can you, please, check the updated post and help me with that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I made some changes. See the Update section for how your Controller should look. Try this and it should work.

Comment: Yeah, you solved exactly the way I was looking for ! I dont't know how to retribute, as this is so important to me. Man, I'm so glad!! God bless you, brother!

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE NOTE: In JSF, the MVC Controllers are NOT user-written code. They are the FacesServlet and tag implementations.

My pedantic streak gets twitchy when people name JSF backing beans "XXXController". A backing bean is a MODEL. The action methods and Listeners are extra-MVC features and not Controller methods. All a Controller does is copy data to and from the View, and, as I said, JSF does that automatically without recourse to user code.

Comment: I'm already aware of it (check the myBean.java). In fact, I've used this way to facilitate for Paul Morris, as he suggested. But thanks for observing it.